# Calling base class method from derived constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, methods, radix

```
class Base {
    public:
    Base() {}

    void Foo(int x) {...}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    Derived(int args) {
        /* process args in some way */

        Foo(result);
    }
};
```

Is it allowed to call a method of the base class in the constructor of the derived class?
I would imagine this is fine as the Base object should be fully constructed, but I wanted to check just in case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it allowed to call a method of the base class in the constructor of the derived class?

Yes. Just watch out for `virtual` functions. If an class derived from `Derived` overrides a virtual function, while constructing `Derived` as a sub-object of that further derived class, the dynamic type always is `Derived`, so no virtual functions overridden in further derived classes are called. (The same goes for the destructor, BTW.)

> I would imagine this is fine as the Base object should be fully constructed, but I wanted to check just in case.

Your reasoning is right.

Answer (score 2):

There is a danger when:
 1. the method is overridden
 2. the method calls other methods that are overridden

Comment: That's plain wrong. There's certainly no problem with overloaded functions and constructors. Do you mean _overridden_? (And if so, don't forget that this applies to virtual functions only.)

Comment: upvoted (and sbi's answer too), but you mean 'overridden', not 'overloaded'

Comment: sbi, in adf88's defense, overridden implies virtual (as otherwise it's hidden, not overridden, and probably a mistake).

Comment: Even though the answer has been edited to talk about _overridden_ and not _overloaded_, it still doesn't explain _what_ the "danger" is. It could be a lot more helpful.

Comment: Corrected. I always mix these two words ;)

Comment: @tpdi: No, it doesn't imply that. You can override non-virtual functions in C++. It's rarely ever useful, but virtual is not implied.